# SwipeRefreshLayout doesn't show any indicator of refreshing

Tags: android, xml, view, fragment, swiperefreshlayout

I have a `SwipeRefreshLayout` being used inside of Fragments that are being displayed in activities. Swiping does perform the refresh, but **after I pull down it goes right back up and there's no indicator of indeterminate progress** (the animated progress bars). It just disappears but *still* calls onRefresh() when it's done. Here's my layouts…

Activity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:dividerHeight="1px"
            android:background="@color/drawer_background_gray"
            android:clipToPadding="false"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Fragment layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ListView
                android:id="@android:id/list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:clipToPadding="false"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <TextView
            android:id="@android:id/empty"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/empty_text_size"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:textColor="@color/brand_green"/>

    <ProgressBar
            android:id="@android:id/progress"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:indeterminateOnly="true"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Code to initialize the `Fragment`'s layout:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, null);
        swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);
        swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
        swipeLayout.setColorScheme(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright,
                android.R.color.holo_green_light,
                android.R.color.holo_orange_light,
                android.R.color.holo_red_light);
        return view;
}
```

There's generally a 3 to 6 second delay while refreshing, enough that it's noticeable while watching the log. It should be visible, and it worked fine when I used the now deprecated `ActionBar-PullToRefresh` library. I've tried making `SwipeRefreshLayout` the root view of the Fragment layout, and I tried removing the empty text and progress view, and it continues to not work.

There's a few more steps that go into my actual code that I can't reveal as it's an app being designed for my company. But it's only for providing a similar base to many different fragments that do similar things, it shouldn't affect any functionality for this.

Comment: Would you edit your post and include your `SwipeRefreshLayout` implementation, please? Is there enough time for the progress bar to actually display or could your data be refreshing too quickly?

Comment: @adneal just added more detail and code

Comment: There isn't anything noticeably wrong with what you've posted or said, at least from what I can tell. You might try implementing some dummy data to see if the problem persists. You could also try calling `SwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true)` rather than pulling down to check and see if the progress bar will appear that way. At any rate, it's kinda weird. You should definitely update your post if you can think of anything else.

Comment: @adneal well all the data is being pulled off of my companies servers, but yeah I'll try manually calling setRefreshing(bool) to see if that works

Comment: @adneal even manually using setRefreshing(true) doesn't work. This is really odd.

Comment: I am having precisely the same problem as afollestad... My SwipeRefreshLayout wraps a listView. In the OnRefreshListener.OnRefresh method, I try forcing the indicator to be on with mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true); You do see the indicator flash on the screen, but it abruptly turns off, even though I never call mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered the issue is that my app uses translucent UI on Android 4.4, padding is set to the top of the list and bottom of the list so that it goes under the action bar and above the navigation bar. Since the ListView becomes a child of the `SwipeRefreshLayout`, the padding should be set to the `SwipeRefreshLayout` instead of the `ListView` like I had been before I switched to using `SwipeRefreshLayout`.

Comment: Can you say me where did you use cliptopadding = false? I am getting my refresh material circle under toolbar and if I add a padding to the swiperefreshlayout, my recyclerView gets cut (even using cliptopadding=false)

Answer (score 11):

I used this below approach and it worked for me without workarounds, even Fragments, after so many tries:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">

      ** content **

    </ScrollView>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

AppCompat Library: `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3`.

Answer (score 0):

```
//to enable 
swipeRefreshLayout.post(new Runnable() {
@Override public void run() {
    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
}});


//to disable 
swipeRefreshLayout.post(new Runnable() {
@Override public void run() {
    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
}});

//IF ABOVE CODE DOESN'T WORK
//you might have made SwipeRefreshLayout as a root layout and it can be the source of bug
//so put SwipeRefreshLayout inside any ViewGroup like RelativeLayout, LinearLayout
```

Comment: This post is old. :P

Answer (score 0):

Change  swipeLayout.setColorScheme() to .setColorSchemeResources(# Your Colors Ids)

Comment: That's unrelated and this post is old.