# SwipeRefreshLayout in API 21

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout

I previously was using API 19 and was using `SwipeRefreshLayout` for many of my fragments. When I loaded content for the first time previously, I was using the `setRefreshing(true);` and was able to load content and it worked fine.

I'm noticing in Android 5.0 Google is using a circular progress view. When I call `setRefreshing(true);` now it simply has no effect. Is there anyway to programmatically show the new spinner? I've delved in to this quite a bit but not able to programmatically show it. I have read the following on this:

http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html

https://yassirh.com/2014/05/how-to-use-swiperefreshlayout-the-right-way/

[SwipeRefreshLayout doesn't show any indicator of refreshing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23661805/swiperefreshlayout-doesnt-show-any-indicator-of-refreshing)

Basically, it shows no indication of refreshing on the first try.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Instead of directly setting

```
getSwipeRefreshLayout().setRefreshing(true);
```

you can delay it on the UI thread for later

```
getSwipeRefreshLayout().post(new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() {
        getSwipeRefreshLayout().setRefreshing(true);
    }
});
```

this works perfectly for me to start loading in `onCreateView` and if done in a `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks` too.

I haven't seen the progress bar accidentally sticking (because the data load is too quick), but if you suspect that the load may return too early (error?) **it's worth to do the same posting** for

```
getSwipeRefreshLayout().setRefreshing(false);
```

this way the two `post`s will definitely come one after the other, resulting in a definitely hidden progress view.

Comment: Please star the following issue if you're having this problem:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77712

Answer (score 1):

This is not a very clean solution, but it works for now. `setRefreshing(boolean)` the progress view is behind the action bar. The solution is to push it down:

```
    Display display = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int height = size.y;
    getSwipeRefreshLayout().setProgressViewOffset(false, -200, height / 9);
```

If you have a better solution, please post it below and I'll accept it!

**Please don't use this solution, the accepted answer is better.**

Comment: This is a disaster. There's MUCH better ways to actually fix this bug instead of hacking stuff together. Downvoted.

Comment: Please read the question and when I posted my answer. At the time `SwipeRefreshLayout` was brand new and there were no good solutions for this.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem,but only in the case of using `StickyListHeadersListView`.
Using `android.widget.ListView`,everything is OK.

I think in api 21,Google has rewritten Listview class。
If you are using Listview subclass,I guess that you might need to make the `subclass exends android.widget.ListView` in api 21.

Comment: Thats very strange. I'm using `android.widget.ListView` or a subclass of it in all places...

Answer (score 0):

What you have to remember is that the Material Design SwipeRefreshLayout has changed, while the old one used the BakedBezierInterpolator, but the new one uses the "dragged into position" progress spinner

Unfortunately API 21 doesn't include the BakedBezierInterpolator anymore, so from my point of view you have 2 options:
1) shift the spinner down (and remember to shift it back up afterwards)
2) make your own spinner to sit on the screen when you're initially loading the data

If you want to keep your spinner the same, then definitely use the SwipeRefreshLayout one, but make sure that you remember to re-position it

I hope this helps in some way...

Answer (score 0):

You can try to call measure(int, int) method before setRefreshing(true)

Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/26692841/2114930.

Answer (score 0):

KVISH, please review my answer on: 
[SwipeRefreshLayout doesn't show any indicator of refreshing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23661805/swiperefreshlayout-doesnt-show-any-indicator-of-refreshing)

The approach is to add your view in a ScrollView widget. If you use AppCompat Library v21.0.3, it would should work.